# Can i play a swf file /flv file in FlowPlayer?

Tags: flash, flowplayer

Can i play a swf file /flv file in FlowPlayer ?

Answer (score 3):

> The anser is yes, although they aren't
>   properly supported in that if it works
>   it works, if it doesn't don't expect
>   the team to fix it for compatibility
>   :)
>
> You can see a demo here of a generic
>   swf file playing in a flowplayer
>   playlist:http://flowplayer.org/demos/playlist/index.html

Source: http://flowplayer.org/forum/2/14874